I have multiple lmer models, how to adjust the p-values for multiple testing?
I couldn't find any similar questions because all the questions I found deal with correcting for multiple comparisons within a single lmer model.
I have a set of lmer models, which always have the same predictor variables, but the outcome measure is different in every analysis. It's hard to make a reproducible example for this because I am doing the analyses on some sensitive data, but in any case this question is more conceptual rather than about the code.
Having 30 lmer models with same predictors and different outcomes, how can I adjust the p-values in the lmer models to avoid alpha error inflation?

@jkd's answer is good, but the short answer is "extract the p-values (using coef(summary(.)) or broom.mixed::tidy() and then use p.adjust()

I usually adjust the p-values within predictor variables in such cases. Here is a MWE:
library(tidyverse)
library(lmerTest)

set.seed(9789)
dat <- data.frame(subject = factor(rep(1:10, each = 2)),
                  timepoint = factor(rep(1:2, 10))) |>
  mutate(pred1 = as.numeric(as.character(subject)) * 0.5 + rnorm(20),
         pred2 = as.numeric(as.character(timepoint)) * 0.2 + rnorm(20),
         outcome1 = pred1 * 0.7 + rnorm(20, 3),
         outcome2 = pred2 * 0.2 + rnorm(20, 1) + pred1,
         outcome3 = pred2 * pred1 - rnorm(20, 5))

res <- dat |>
  pivot_longer(starts_with("outcome"), names_to = "outcome", values_to = "dv") |>
  nest(.by = outcome) |>
  mutate(fit = map(data, \(d) lmer(dv ~ pred1 * pred2 + timepoint + (1 | subject), data = d)))

## check your models individually
## res$fit[[1]]
## summary(res$fit[[1]])
## plot(res$fit[[1]])
## car::qqPlot(resid(res$fit[[1]]))
## ...

res |>
  mutate(aov = map(fit, \(d) broom::tidy(anova(d)) |> rename(`F` = statistic)),
         es = map(fit, \(d) effectsize::eta_squared(d) |> select(-Parameter))) |>
  unnest(c(aov, es)) |>
  mutate(p.adj = p.adjust(p.value, "holm"), .after = "p.value", .by = term) |>
  select(-data, -fit, -CI)

# A tibble: 12 × 12
   outcome  term          sumsq  meansq NumDF DenDF      F     p.value       p.adj Eta2_partial  CI_low CI_high
   <chr>    <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 outcome1 pred1       25.0    25.0        1 12.5  98.0   0.000000286 0.000000858       0.887  0.753         1
 2 outcome1 pred2        1.01    1.01       1 14.7   3.96  0.0657      0.134             0.212  0             1
 3 outcome1 timepoint    0.0711  0.0711     1  9.47  0.278 0.610       0.758             0.0285 0             1
 4 outcome1 pred1:pred2  2.00    2.00       1 14.1   7.83  0.0142      0.0283            0.358  0.0538        1
 5 outcome2 pred1       14.5    14.5        1 14.9  38.4   0.0000174   0.0000347         0.720  0.472         1
 6 outcome2 pred2        0.276   0.276      1 10.3   0.733 0.411       0.411             0.0663 0             1
 7 outcome2 timepoint    0.570   0.570      1  8.21  1.51  0.253       0.758             0.156  0             1
 8 outcome2 pred1:pred2  0.103   0.103      1  9.93  0.274 0.612       0.612             0.0269 0             1
 9 outcome3 pred1        0.0811  0.0811     1 12.3   0.148 0.707       0.707             0.0119 0             1
10 outcome3 pred2        2.65    2.65       1 14.8   4.82  0.0445      0.134             0.245  0.00393       1
11 outcome3 timepoint    0.647   0.647      1  9.65  1.18  0.304       0.758             0.109  0             1
12 outcome3 pred1:pred2 14.2    14.2        1 14.3  25.9   0.000155    0.000465          0.644  0.348         1

The adjustment for multiple comparison is performed within groups defined by term, a variable introduced by anova, which provides p-values for each predictor. This is simplified by keeping the models together using the nesting method provided by tidyr (loaded via library(tidyverse)), but of course you can concatenate the anova tables of each model or retrieve the p values provided to p.adjust manually.

But does the OP want to apply the p-value adjustment termwise, or for the entire set of p-values from the analysis?

@BenBolker Could you help me understand the difference between the two? Isn't applying the adjustment termwise, but for every term, in the end the same thing as adjusting the entire set of p-values?

@J.Doe to adjust for the entire set of p values you would just leave out the .by = term part of the mutate statement. This means that in my example you would adjust all 12 p values as one set instead of 4 sets of three p values (one set per term for three outcomes). This is a more conservative approach (i.e., gives "higher"  adjusted p values). Which to chose depends on the study design and the conclusions you want to draw. Adjusting within terms would be adequate if you want to state something like "pred1 was significantly associated with following outcomes" (placatively).

... you should also consider the potential repercussions of false positives (do you want to be conservative because a lot depends on a significant result?), the number of outcomes for which you run the analysis (and the rationale for considering all those outcomes), and the potential association between predictors (are they truly independent).

To understand the difference between term wise and for the entire set just run p.adjust four times for three sets of p values and once for the concatenated sets. The latter gives higher p values because you consider more p values at once and thus have a higher implicit probability of false positives.

@jkd Thans for the explanation, I have just one follow up question. If I am using the joint_tests function from emmeans because I have categorical predictors with more than 2 levels and I want an overall p-value for the variable instead of the "dummy" p-values, how do I make adjustments in the p-values there?  Some adjustment happens already when "concatenating" these levels, and should the "overall" adjustment then happen before that, after that, or not at all?

I realized my last comment might be more appropriate for a question on Cross Validated. I will post there.

Independently of how you obtain the p values (my method does provide overall p-values and the method suggested by Ben Bolker with broom.mixed does as well), you generally obtain the p-values for each model and then perform the desired adjustment for multiple comparisons. emmeans::joint_tests is applied to each model separately and thus does not perform any p value adjustment for multiple comparisons. Please note that generally, post-hoc comparisons should be performed only if the adjusted p value is significant.

I also believe that if you have only categorical predictors joint_tests should provide very similar p values to the ones obtained with the above method.
